# Firebase Query - Find user matching email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a query to find a user that matches a certain email. When I perform the query, I get all of the emails in the database. My final objective is to find this user with his or her email and then update the `InMatch` and `SearchingForUser` key values. This is my code:

```
func fetchUsersSearchingForMatch() {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let user = AppUser()


    ref.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            user.userEmail = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["email"] as? String
            user.searchingForMatch = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["SearchingForMatch"] as? Bool)!
            print(dictionary)
            if user.searchingForMatch == true {
                self.users.append(user)
                self.foundUser = self.users[0]
                print("this is your foundUser \(self.foundUser.userEmail)")
                print("this number of users are searching for a match: \(self.users.count)")
            }
        }
        self.foundUserSearchingForMatch()
    })
}


func foundUserSearchingForMatch() {

    if user.inMatch == false {

        let query = self.ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: foundUser.userEmail)
        print("this is the query \(query)")
    }
}
```

I am not doing any updating until I know that I am selecting the right user. When I do, how do you update the values? Can I do it inside the query?

JSON TREE:

```
{"Firebase APP": {
    "RANDOM USER ID": {
        "USEREMAIL": "email@example.com",
        "SearchingForMatch": "true",
        "InMatch": "false" }
}
```

When the user finds a match, I want to change the `InMatch` key to `true` and the `SearchingForMatch` to `false`.

I don't want to update my email or the `foundUser` email. I want to update the `foundUser`, `InMatch`, and `SearchingForMatch` key values.

The way I get the email from the user looking for a match from FBDB is when I check if `SearchingForMatch` equals `true` in all of my users, if it does equal `true`, I append it to an array and then get the first element's email (which is now the `foundUser`). Using the `foundUser` email, I want to update that users key values (`InMatch` and `SearchingForMatch`).

Comment: Give your JSON tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
     FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.updateEmail("new_Email", completion: { (Err) in
        if Err == nil {

            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "USEREMAIL").queryEqual(toValue: ).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snap) in

                if let snapDict = Snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                    for each in snapDict{

                     let key = each.key
                     let match = each.value["SearchingForMatch"] as! Bool                        
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users/\(key)").updateChildValues(["SearchingForMatch" : "true"], withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                            if err == nil{
                               //Task acomplished....
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }else{
        //Couldn't update the auth value.
        }
    })
```

Comment: So, I do not want to update the email just the InMatch and SearchingForUser keys. Wouldn't the first line change the email?

Comment: Yes it will also update the email... But if you just wanna update your email in FBDB, just start from ` `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")...`

Comment: ok, I dont want to update my email or the foundUser email. I want to update the foundUser InMatch and SearchingForMatch key values. I get the email from the user looking for a match from FBDB when I check if SearchingForMatch equals true in all of my users, if it does I append it to an array and then get the first element's email (which is now the foundUser). Using the foundUser email I want to update that users key values.

Comment: Answer updated. The each segment that you recieve in the for loop will be the  required dictionary... I am not going to write the entire code for your... I am sure you can figure out..:) Happy Coding

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. Will accept the answer as soon as I give it a try later today.